# How to reference something in superscript?

Tags: cross-referencing, superscripts

When I reference some label with `\ref{label}` I find the reference a little too big (Because it's the same size as everything else) I'd like them to be in superscript. But not everywhere. 
I want this behavior when I mention a figure/section. An alternative command would be preferable.

Example:

*picture of a dinosaur* -
fig. 1.

Dinosaurs<sup>1</sup> do move in herds

Comment: You want `see section \ref{sec:foo}` to produce  "see section ² "  won't that look rather strange?

Comment: That really would look strange. Maybe I chose my words poorly. The use case is not worded like this, the referencing itself is not part of the sentence, it's more like a citation. Like, when I mention something shown in a figure and I just want to have a reference there, in superscript.

Is that a bad-practice?

Comment: Please edit your posting, including its title, to focus on what you really wish to achieve. Please be as clear as you can, and give as many relevant examples as you can think of.

Comment: but you are asking to globally change the way `\ref` works, which would have the effect I show.  superscripts, whether for footnotes or citation usually have no preceding space, so it is hard to guess how you see this working it would help if you made a small complete (one page) document  and you showed examples of the expected input and output.  (`\let\oldref=\ref \def\ref#1{\textsuperscript{\oldref{#1}}` does what you ask but I can't believe that is really what you want.

Comment: I edited my question. Now that you mention, changing `\ref` globally, really is a bad idea. I might want to use it normally later.

Comment: @GyőriSándor: Wouldn't this style of referencing be confusing for ther reader? What happens if you have a `figure 1`, a `table 1` and a `chapter1`/`section 1`? How does the reader know to which of them the superscript number refers to?  What about footnotes and citations (if a numeric citation style is used)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you load the `cleveref` package (and, optionally, the `hyperref` package) and proceed by issuing `\crefformat` instructions to inform LaTeX that cross-references to `figure` and `table` environments created with `\cref` should be typeset in superscript-numeric format.

[image]

With this setup, you can still use the ordinary `\ref` command to create non-superscript cross-references.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev]{cleveref}
\crefformat{figure}{\textsuperscript{#2#1#3}}
\crefformat{table}{\textsuperscript{#2#1#3}}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}\caption{Dinosaurs}\label{fig:din}\end{figure}
\begin{table} \caption{Numbers}  \label{tab:num}\end{table}
Dinosaurs\cref{fig:din} \dots

Numbers\cref{tab:num} \dots
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! Cleveref fits my needs exactly!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I wanted to `\ref` items in `enumerate` in superscript, which at first I thought could be solved with `cleveref` and setting `crefdefaultlabelformat` to `\textsuperscript{#2#1#3}` but that resulted in "item" written before any reference. Final solution was to create a new command which doesn't need any packages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\sref}[1]{\textsuperscript{\ref{#1}}}

Foo\sref{foo}
 
\begin{enumerate}
    \item \label{foo} bar
\end{enumerate}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!